# HTML form not triggering "submit" event listener when form is submitted

Tags: html, forms, dom, addeventlistener

I have an event listener attached to an HTML form element, but the listener is not getting triggered when I click on the button that submits the form or press "enter".

Here is the HTML:

```html
<main class="main">
  <div class="login-form">
    <h2 class="heading-secondary ma-bt-lg">Log into your account</h2>
    <form class="form" id="loginform">
      <div class="form__group">
        <label class="form__label" for="email">Email address</label>
        <input class="form__input" id="email" type="email" placeholder="you@example.com" required="required"/>
      </div>
      <div class="form__group ma-bt-md">
        <label class="form__label" for="password">Password</label>
        <input class="form__input" id="password" type="password" placeholder="••••••••" required="required" minlength="8"/>
      </div>
      <div class="form__group">
        <button class="btn btn--green" type="submit">Login</button>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</main>
```

Here is the event listener JS code:

```js
const loginForm = document.getElementById('loginform');

if (loginForm) {
  loginForm.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log('Hello from the login event listener');
    const email = document.getElementById('email').value;
    const password = document.getElementById('password').value;
    login(email, password);
  });
}
```

And here is the JS code for the function `login(email, password)`, which is imported from another file:

```js
export const login = async (email, password) => {
  try {
    const res = await axios({
      method: 'POST',
      url: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/users/login',
      data: {
        email,
        password,
      },
    });

    if (res.data.status === 'success') {
      showAlert('success', 'Logged in successfully!');
      window.setTimeout(() => {
        location.assign('/home');
      }, 1500);
    }
  } catch (err) {
    showAlert('error', err.response.data.message);
  }
};
```

Troubleshooting steps I've taken:

1. I verified that the 'submit' event listener is actually attached to the form element -- I can see it in the "event listeners" tab of the Chrome dev tools
2. I verified that the browser is registering clicks to the submit button. I did this by adding an event listener to the body element and sending event.target to the console log. When I click on the submit button, the browser registers that the submit button is being clicked, but the 'submit' event listener attached to the form is not triggered.
3. I tested another event listener on the page and it still worked. Though, oddly, none of my anchor elements are redirecting to the href when clicked anymore -- I don't know whether this is related in any way to my form not submitting.

Comment: remove `export` from `const login`

Comment: Thanks for your comment! The login function is in a separate file (login.js), so I need the export statement. I did not show it in the snippet above, but the JS file with the event listener (index.js) includes an import statement to access the login function from login.js.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the problem. It was a dumb mistake on my part. In working to diagnose another problem, I'd added an event listener to the body element so that I could verify that click events were being generated (and see where they were being generated) when various DOM elements were clicked. BUT... I included an event.preventDefault() statement in that event listener, which shut down the default behavior on whatever was being clicked -- including the form element. Once I removed the event listener the form worked properly.

Thanks for your help everyone!

Answer (score 3):

Your code seems to work fine.  I get a console statement when I submit the form.

Keep in mind that the submit event is not triggered until the form is valid though!  Since you put a `required` attribute on both text fields, then the email must not be blank and must be a valid email since you specified `type="email"`, and the password must not be blank and must be at least 8 characters long since you specified `minlength="8"`

```js
const loginForm = document.getElementById('loginform');

if (loginForm) {
  loginForm.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log('Hello from the login event listener');
    const email = document.getElementById('email').value;
    const password = document.getElementById('password').value;
    //login(email, password);
  });
}
```

```html
<main class="main">
  <div class="login-form">
    <h2 class="heading-secondary ma-bt-lg">Log into your account</h2>
    <form class="form" id="loginform">
      <div class="form__group">
        <label class="form__label" for="email">Email address</label>
        <input class="form__input" id="email" type="email" placeholder="you@example.com" required="required"/>
      </div>
      <div class="form__group ma-bt-md">
        <label class="form__label" for="password">Password</label>
        <input class="form__input" id="password" type="password" placeholder="••••••••" required="required" minlength="8"/>
      </div>
      <div class="form__group">
        <button class="btn btn--green" type="submit">Login</button>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</main>
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment! It is very helpful to know that the code worked fine for you. I did make sure that the email and password fields contained valid entries before trying to submit the form and it still didn't work for me. But if it's working for you then I'll need to consider causes outside of the code I excerpted.

Comment: Check the snippet in my answer above. That’s where I have it working just fine